# Primefaces datatable used to display non updateable database view results?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, primefaces-datatable

Good day

Is it possible (I seem to be stuck at not being able to click the 'tick' to accept a row edit) to use a Primefaces datatable to display the result of a non updateable Postgres view, but have custom code in the onRowEdit event that will persist the changes correctly to the DB?

Or MUST a Primefaces / JSF datatable be linked to an updateable entity mapping in order for it to be used to 'update' and display info?

I have in the .xhtml file this:

```
 <p:dataTable id="conf_data_table" var="confRoomBookingDisplay" style="width: auto" rowIndexVar="rowid" editingRow="true"
                             value="#{conferenceRoomBookingView.conferenceRoomBookingList}" editable="true"
                             editMode="row" widgetVar="cellBookings">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Venue Booking
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{conferenceRoomBookingView.onRowEdit}"
                            update=":create_new_booking:growl"/>
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{conferenceRoomBookingView.onRowCancel}"
                            update=":create_new_booking:growl"/>

                    <p:column headerText="Booking Ref" style="width: 10%; text-align: center">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{ConferenceRoomBooking.conferenceRoomBookingAid}"
                                       style="text-align: center"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Time Slot" style="width: 10%; text-align: center">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{ConferenceRoomBooking.timeSlot}" style="text-align: center"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Booked For" style="width: 15%; alignment: center">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{ConferenceRoomBooking.empShortNameSurname}"
                                       style="text-align: left"/>
                    </p:column>


                    <p:column headerText="Booking Comment" style="width: 60%; alignment: center">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ConferenceRoomBooking.conferenceRoomBookingComment}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{ConferenceRoomBooking.conferenceRoomBookingComment}"
                                             style="width:98%"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width: 5%">
                        <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>

                </p:dataTable>
```

And then on my @RequestScoped (javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped) @Named backing bean (I tried it with a @ViewScoped - org.omnifaces.cdi annotation as well).

The event code looks like this:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    conferenceRoomBookingAid = (((ConferenceRoomBookingEntity) event.getObject()).getConferenceRoomBookingAid());
    String msgEdit = Long.toString(conferenceRoomBookingAid);
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Booking Edited for Reference ID:", msgEdit);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    confRoomService.persistComment(How do I get my updated value from the event???);
}

public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
    conferenceRoomBookingAid = (((ConferenceRoomBookingEntity) event.getObject()).getConferenceRoomBookingAid());
    String msgEdit = Long.toString(conferenceRoomBookingAid);
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Booking Cancelled for Reference ID: ", msgEdit);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

Currently commenting out the `confRoomService.persistComment(How do I get my updated value from the event???);` code, gets me to a properly rendered table where I am able to edit the row. The problem however is that I can not click the 'accept' / 'yes' tick with the mouse, and pressing enter just clears the cell again.

The reason I am using a non updateable view is that the current DB structure uses foreign keys to link the data to persons, and using the base entity will display the foreign key id instead of its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of different versions of Entities and database views, I came to the conclusion that the JSF / Primefaces datatable component is meant to be used:

1. When linked directly via an Entity that is mutable, and thus a 100% representation of the underlying database table, with no custom views of the data, full editing is allowed and works as advertised.
2. When linked to an Entity that is based on a Database View (updateable or not), the cells / rows of the datatable cannot be edited in the datatable cellEdit or rowEdit events.

I would be ecstatic if proved wrong on the above, but for now have made peace with using the datatable as immutable when based on a database view.

Comment: I'd say that 2 is not a problem of the datatable but a limitation in general (not even jsf but beyond that) and only can be circumvented if you write the custom code

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your feeding sir. With regards to writing the custom code, I would if it was possible to inititate the rowEdit event (by being able to actually click on the 'tick' in the rowedit component. But not even that is possible, I cannot click the 'tick'. Must one overide the complete Primefaces rowEdit function?

Comment: I don't see why not being able to click on the edit button is related to using read-only views.

Comment: @Kukeltje What I wanted to do in essence was create a mutable representation of the PostgreSQL view. I wanted to implement it by running my custom jpa persist code AFTER the rowEdit tick mark has been pressed. However, if the data linked to the datatable is not mutable, you can click 10000 times on the tick icon, but nothing happens. The rowEdit code is not executed. It is as if the 'tick' is disabled. Therefore it is not possible to have custom code execute after the tick has been pressed (which implies 'save the row') because clicking the 'tick' is impossible.

Comment: @Kukeltje Or were you refering to including a custom <p:commandButton> / <p:commandLink> in each row, and thus not using the <p:rowEditor> component at all?

Comment: I still fail to see where the datatable plays an active role here. The datatable does not know if the entity that is used in displaying it cannot be persisted in the datatable. Especially since the datatable does not do any persising at all. It just makes sure the value is send from the client to the server. If the 'tick' does not work, that is most likely because the action **you** do on the tick prevents it from working. Check the logging for errors, add a `p:messages` etc... there most likely is something wrong in your (custom) code.

Comment: @Kukeltje aah, thanks. So my code in the public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) is 'broken' and that the 'tick' 'sees' that ahead in the code to come, and therefore behaves as if it is read only? If so, could you pretty please enlighten me as to what is broken in my code above in the onRowEdit method (when the persist is commented out). According to me, I should atleast see the growl when the tick is pressed?

Comment: Well, no not that sort of seeing 'ahead'... Most likely if there is an error in the code that is executed. Start by setting a breakpoint and debug...

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks will do.